# Bibtex "didn't find a database entry"

Tags: bibtex, warnings

I'm having issues creating citations in my document. My text file states:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}

Their long-term aid \citet{Haggarty:01}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Quotes}

\end{document}
```

My bibtex file is:

```
\begin{thebibliography}

\bibitem[Haggarty and Pepin(2001)]{Haggarty:01}
L. Haggarty and B. Pepin.
\newblock An Investigation of Mathematics Textbooks and their use in English, French and German Classrooms.
\newblock \emph{Proceedings of the British Society for Research into Learning Mathematics}, 21\penalty0 (2):\penalty0 117--125, 2001.

\end{thebibliography}
```

When I latex, bibtex, latex, latex I get the following warning:

```
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Haggarty:01"
```

I've creating references like this before a long time ago, so I can't remember if there's anything else I should be doing. I've tried deleting the .aux file before running a fresh but nothing seems to help. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: That is not how a `BibTeX` file must be constructed.  See the document *Tame the Beast* for information. Use `texdoc ttb` if you have TeX Live installed) or go to [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net) and search for 'ttb' there.

Comment: Your "bibtex" file isn't in the format that BibTeX expects it to be in. Instead, it would appear to be in `.bbl` format, i.e., a file produced by a combination of BibTeX and LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

Your file `Quotes.bib` should look like this:

```
@Article{Haggarty:01,
  author =   {Haggarty, L. and Pepin, B.},
  title =    {An Investigation of Mathematics Textbooks and their
                  use in English, French and German Classrooms},
  journal =  {Proceedings of the British Society for Research into
                  Learning Mathematics},
  year =     2001,
  volume =   21,
  number =   2,
  pages =    {117--125}
}
```

Compiling your main file with `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex` gives:

[image: Sample output]

What you have used instead is something akin to the `.bbl` file that is the result of running `latex` followed by `bibtex`.  Once you have a final list of references such a `.bbl` file could be included directly in to your main source to make a standand alone document of the form:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}

Their long-term aid \citet{Haggarty:01}

%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
%\bibliography{Quotes}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[Haggarty and Pepin(2001)]{Haggarty:01}
L.~Haggarty and B.~Pepin.
\newblock An investigation of mathematics textbooks and their use in english,
  french and german classrooms.
\newblock \emph{Proceedings of the British Society for Research into Learning
  Mathematics}, 21\penalty0 (2):\penalty0 117--125, 2001.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and here it was solved:

I have a main tex file calling all other chapters including reference, and the tex file of each of these chapters are in a separate folder. If you ever used a template to produce a PhD thesis you know what I mean.

In my reference folder however I have 2 files, one **references.tex** and another one **references.bib** and I was updating the .tex file and not the .bib file at the same time. Silly mistake really but believe me among all those corrections & editions it could easily happen.
Anyhow make sure both your .tex and .bib file are identical if you are in a similar situation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized, I also have to use `\citep{}` for the added bibliography entry, somewhere in the text for the bibliography entry to show up.